# Where to put system-wide language-specific Vim ftplugin .vim files

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I've put some language-agnostic baseline settings in `/etc/vimrc`, which serve as default for users unless a user overrides them.

Where is the canonical *system-wide* place to put the respective `{language}.vim` files?

On a per-user basis, I've always put these in `~/.vim/ftplugin/{language}.vim`, i.e. `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` might contain:

```
setlocal colorcolumn=72,80
```

However, this only kicks in for the given user.

Where should the system-wide version of `~/.vim/ftplugin/` sit?  Should I directly edit `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim`, or override it somewhere else?

---

Info:

Output of `:scriptnames`:

```
/etc/vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/dockerfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/nginx.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/stp.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/cctree.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
```

Output of `:h runtimepath`:

```
'runtimepath' 'rtp'     string  (default:
                                       Unix: "$HOME/.vim,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles,
                                               $VIMRUNTIME,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                                               $HOME/.vim/after"
                                       Amiga: "home:vimfiles,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles,
                                               $VIMRUNTIME,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                                               home:vimfiles/after"
                                       PC, OS/2: "$HOME/vimfiles,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles,
                                               $VIMRUNTIME,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                                               $HOME/vimfiles/after"
                                       Macintosh: "$VIM:vimfiles,
                                               $VIMRUNTIME,
                                               $VIM:vimfiles:after"
                                       RISC-OS: "Choices:vimfiles,
                                               $VIMRUNTIME,
                                               Choices:vimfiles/after"
                                       VMS: "sys$login:vimfiles,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles,
                                               $VIMRUNTIME,
                                               $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                                               sys$login:vimfiles/after")
```

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: Thanks @filbranden, will do so in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to override `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim` globally put your code into `$VIM/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/python.vim` (it's mentioned in `:help runtimepath` above); `$VIM` is usually `/usr/share/vim` so the exact path is `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. Those plugins are executed **after** main plugins. Per-user overrides are in `$HOME/.vim/after`.

Verify paths with `:echo &runtimepath`.